# How does ambient temperature affect material conductivity

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In the book I read I found many contradiction as to how ambient temperature affect material conductivity. Here is an example:

[image]

Highlighted sentences are cntradictions - "Does any termal energy create free electron in silicon?" The answer is no so I concluded ok temperature does not affect conductivity. But later on we can read "...number of electrons depends on Eq and T ", plus at the beginning of the chapter they say "Silicon crystal vehaves as an insulator for T -> 0K. However ar higher temperatures electrons gain thermal energy...and acting as free charge carierrs".

I am lost..how to explain all of it? To me it looks like we need some energy to make pure silicon a conductor and this is so called "Band Gap" energy which can be gained by temperature rise.

Comment: But energy is not temperature. One can have a large heat reservoir at 1 K that contains (and can contribute) an enormous amount of energy despite its relatively low temperature.

Comment: Also, I wonder if there's a misconception regarding the phrase "any thermal energy," which means "any arbitrarily small amount of thermal energy" rather than "thermal energy at all". The italicization of "any" is meant to emphasize the former meaning.

Comment: This indeed is unclear. Read: Although a typical thermal energy, $kT $, is much smaller than the bandgap, at $T>0$ there are electrons and holes etc.